# Buildmaster 4.3.9 - Assembly SourceGear was not found

Tags: buildmaster

Got this error trying to setup a deployment.  Using the latest version of BuildMaster  Version 4.3.9 (Build 2) and Vault Standard V7.  I've installed the Vault extension within BuildMaster.

*ERROR: Assembly SourceGear was not found. The extension may be out of date, have been deleted, or could not be loaded.
Parameter name: assemblyName*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error typically means that the service cannot load the SourceGear assembly; your best bet is to restart the service, and hope it works again. If it's continually a problem, then you can run the service interactively to see why the assembly can't be loaded.

Usually, it's an access/permission problem, or anti-virus.

Comment: Karl - Restarting the service did work. Thanks for your reply!